# How to bypass ISP restrictions in ubuntu?

Tags: internet

My institute blocks even the ubuntu servers and i can't even update and upgrade or install new packages. If there's any solution (Note: VPN's and TOR are blocked) please mention

Comment: For upgrading, you could find out what packages need upgrading, then download the .deb files somewhere else and put them on an USB stick or perhaps share them over the local network. But that would mean you know exactly what dependencies each package has, which is a bit of a hassle.

Comment: Don’t you just need to use a HTTP proxy? APT can be configured for that.

Comment: All ubuntu servers? You could try and change download servers. See if this helps. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Answer (score 1):

You need internet access for this. If ethernet is out all you have is wireless. If there is no access point you need to move to a location that has.

If the institute you are at does not want you to update your system nor install software you are not going to get this working over their network.